# json encode of multiple arrays using php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have an arrays like follows:

```
Array
(
    [option] => nos
    [optioncost] => 10
)

Array
(
    [option] => opts
    [optioncost] => 20
)

Array
(
    [option] => opts
    [optioncost] => 30
)
```

need to convert this as like the following json format

```
[{"option":nos,"optioncost":10},{"option":opts,"optioncost":20},{"option":optse,"optioncost":30}]
```

Comment: you created different array. create single array and push data on different index.

Comment: thanks for the reply....i have six different input fileds how to make them as single array

Comment: If you have a fixed number of arrays, you can do `$arr=[$arr1,$arr2,$arr3];`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
    <?php

    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = array('option' => 'nos',
    'optioncost' => 10
    );

    $arr[] = array('option' => 'opts',
    'optioncost' => 20
    );
    $arr[] = array('option' => 'optse',
    'optioncost' => 30
    );



    echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>
```

Output :

```
  [{"option":"nos","optioncost":10},{"option":"opts","optioncost":20},{"option":"opts","optioncost":30}]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Why would the OP try your code? **You should always provide an explanation whenever possible**.

Answer (score 0):

The `json` example you've provided **isn't valid** because `strings` aren't quoted (nos / opts), something you could have easily tested on any [online json validator](https://jsonlint.com/).
You'll need to construct *proper* arrays - where strings are "quoted" - and use the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, i.e.:

```
$arr1 = ['option' => "nos", 'optioncost' => 10];
$arr2 = ['option' => "opts", 'optioncost' => 20];
$arr3 = ['option' => "opts", 'optioncost' => 30];
echo json_encode([$arr1, $arr2, $arr3]);
# [{"option":"nos","optioncost":10},{"option":"opts","optioncost":20},{"option":"opts","optioncost":30}]
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/xt4rC4)

---

Note:

`Strings` need to be quoted, but `floats`, `ints` or `bools` don't.